# How can I set printer property in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to make sure that when printing from Access it does not go to Windows default printer but to a printer of my choice (via vba code). Also I need to set it for duplex printing. Is it possible? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

It happens to my users that when they print something from a different application (let's say MS Word) and change the printer's property it stays set like that in Win10 and printing a report from Access then uses the new printer property. It also happened that Win10 changed the default printer to a totally different printer and the report went somewhere else. Only remedy I found I disallowed auto change of default printer in Windows.

Comment: When printing what? Reports have printer properties. This question is a bit too broad in my opinion, start by reviewing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/printing/work-with-form-and-report-printer-settings and https://web.archive.org/web/20150331120056/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828638 (unfortunately Microsoft has taken a lot of help offline)

Comment: After your edit: what have you actually tried to lock down printer settings for a report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question how to set a printer, you could try this.

```
Application.Printer = Application.Printers("Microsoft Print to PDF") 'Or the name of the printer.

'You can get the number of available printers by 
Application.Printers.Count

Application.Printers(index).DeviceName 'Would give you name of a printer from the list
```